# Unable to make a circle with border-radius and align it vertically with next element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here is the outcome

[image]

What I want to achieve are

1. A gray circle surrounding the '<' with the letter in the center
2. It and 'untitled' aligns vertically to the center

However despite setting the width and height to the same size, the 'circle' still ends up in an oval shape.

The use of flex's  `align-items: center;` also fails to achieve the alignment.

How can I fix the css? Here is a link to the sample code

**html**

```
<div class='flex-container'>   
  <div class='arrow-container'>
      <a class='btn-icon' href='#'>
        <span class='square-btn icon icon-back'></span>
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class=title>
        <a href='#'>Untitled
        </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.icon-back::before {
  content: '<';
}

.title {
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.square-btn {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;  
}

.btn-icon {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a single html element and pseude-elements. One neat advantage of making everything depend on the font-size is, that the icon scales proportionally with the font size of the link.

```css
.link {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-left: 1.1em;
}

.icon {
  position: relative;
}

.icon-back::before {
  content: '<';
  position: absolute;
  left: -.9em;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
}

.icon-back::after {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -1.1em;
  /* Use translateX() and translateY()
  if you care about old browsers */
  transform: translate3d(0, -45%, 0);
}
```

```html
<a class="link icon icon-back" href="#">Untitled</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the idea of a simpler html markup structure.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work. No changes to HTML.

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.icon {
    font-size: 50px;
}

.icon-back::before {
    content: '<';
}

.title {
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.square-btn {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;                    /* new */
    background-color: gray;                /* new */
    display: flex;                         /* new */
    align-items: center;                   /* new; align arrow vertically */
    justify-content: center;               /* new; align arrow horizontally */
}

.btn-icon {
    /* padding: 5px;                        <-- remove */
    /* border-radius: 50%;                  <-- remove */
    /* background-color: gray;              <-- remove */
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-container'>
    <div class='arrow-container'>
        <a class='btn-icon' href='#'>
            <span class='square-btn icon icon-back'></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class=title>
        <a href='#'>Untitled
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fh19tbrx/)

Comment: For me the "<" is not centered inside the circle

Comment: It's the font size. If you reduce the size (or use a different font) the centering is more precise.

Comment: Depending on the design that may not be an option to reduce the font size dramatically.

Comment: This is a good observation! I would like to position the arrow nicely in the center

Comment: The arrow is more precisely centered here than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Grouping classes makes things harder, also, use unicode in css content when it's not alpha-numerical text, try this:

```
<div class="flex-container">   
<div class="arrow-container">
  <a class="btn-icon" href="#">
    <span class="icon-back"></span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="title">
    <a href="#">Untitled
    </a>
</div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">

.flex-container {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}


.btn-icon {
 font-size: 50px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.icon-back::before {
 content: "\003c";
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: gray;
 font-size: 40px;
 height:40px;
width:40px;
vertical-align:middle;
display:inline-block;
margin-bottom:5px;
text-align:center;
}

.title {
margin-left: 5px;
font-size: 50px;
}




</style>
```

Comment: eh, i whipped that off quickly, you can remove the extra span and assign the before to the link. I assumed you wanted two links here ("back" and "untitled"), otherwise the guy above is correct.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I want to have two links